# Attribute on function to identify which exceptions it might throw using .net

Tags: .net, attributes, resharper

Is there a way to decorate a function with attributes to tell the consumer/developer using that function what kind of exceptions it might throw.

I am hoping for some kind of attribute, with an array of exception types, wich R# could use when wrapping that function in a try/catch to automaticly generate the list for various exceptions in the try/catch statement.

Comment: Or you could use the [Agent Johnson plugin](http://code.google.com/p/agentjohnsonplugin/). Someone obviously thought it useful to create it and it's entirely up to yourself if you want to go down that route. =)

Comment: Urg. Trying to force Java conventions on C#?

Comment: You can decorate a function with any attributes your care to create. But there's no standard one for this, they didn't go down the Java route of checked exceptions, so don't expect any R# support, and don't expect anything to *validate* that the list given in the attribute corresponds with reality.

Comment: I don't see this as being useful - exception handling shouldn't be automated, IMHO. You should think about what you are doing and how to deal with exceptions. Some possible exceptions you shouldn't catch.